# How to add database name dynamically in a table while update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 50 databases and each of them has a `tblEmp` table. There is one row in `tblEmp` table in each database. I want to update some column data in `tblEmp`.

I have written below script for to update one column in `tblEmp` table. There is a challenge in update statement. I am getting all database name by using this script.

```
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

and I'm looping over each row (each database), then I want to update the `tblEmp` table in that database.

My question is how to add database name dynamically along with Update statement. Please see my SQL scripts below.

```
DECLARE @totalRecords int
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE @userData AS TABLE (dbName NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @userData       
    SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 

SET @totalRecords = @@rowcount

WHILE (@totalRecords > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @emptextout NVARCHAR(max) 
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @name = dbName FROM @userData             

    DECLARE @empdefaulttext nvarchar(max) = (N'SELECT @emptextout = CAST(empInfo AS NVARCHAR(max)) FROM '+@name +'.dbo.tblEmp')
 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @empdefaulttext,@Params=N'@emptextout NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT', @emptextout = @emptextout OUTPUT

    -- Here in update statement how to add database name dynamically. It should be as Update **DBName.dbo.tblEmp** set..
    UPDATE tblEmp 
    SET empInfo = REPLACE(@emptextout, 'Rajesh', 'InfoRajesh')
  
    SET @totalRecords = @totalRecords - 1
        
    DELETE FROM @userData 
    WHERE dbname = @name
END
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL the same as you are already for the previous statement. No SQL statement takes a variable as a database, table or column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dale K mentioned:

```
set @empdefaulttext = N'Update '+@name +N'.dbo.tblEmp 
    SET empInfo = REPLACE(@emptextout, ''Rajesh'', ''Kuthrapali'')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @empdefaulttext,@Params=N'@emptextout NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT', @emptextout = @emptextout OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thank You. I have added one more Replace function . Its working now as expected.